# extract info from file name function stringr::str_split_n not exist

Tags: r, stringr

```
filename <-'Income Statement Dax 2020-03-31.xlsx'
```

I want to get the first string ('Income') and the third-string 'Dax' separately

according 
https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_split.html 
I can use function `str_split_n()`
but have the error:

> Error in str_split_n(filename, " ", 3) :    could not find function
>   "str_split_n"

Wondering is function `stringr::str_split_n()` still in use?
if not, any suggestion I can use

```
stringr::str_split (filename, ' ')
```

combine with any another commend to get the first string ('Income') and the third-string 'Dax' separately?

I want to finally achieve:

```
     file<- 'Income'
           sheet <- 'Dax'
dmap <- readxl::read_excel(file, sheet = sheet ) %>% ungroup()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `strsplit(filename, " ")`

Comment: `file <- filename %>% str_split(" ") %>% unlist() %>% nth(1)` and 
`sheet <- filename %>% str_split(" ") %>% unlist() %>% nth(3)`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
parts <- str_split(filename, " ")
file <- parts[[1]][1]
sheet <- parts[[1]][3]

file
sheet
```

gives

```
[1] "Income"
[1] "Dax"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26172558)

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

You need to use `str_split_i()` instead of `str_split_n()`

```
filename <-'Income Statement Dax 2020-03-31.xlsx'

file <- str_split_i(filename, ' ', 1)
sheet <- str_split_i(filename, ' ', 3)
dmap <- readxl::read_excel(file, sheet = sheet ) %>% ungroup()
```